# remapping the caps lock key to less than greater than and pipe key

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, locale

I recently moved from laptop to desktop. But I have a problem.

I bought a cheap chinamade keyboard. However, this keyboard package said, that is was good for german keymap. Upon inspection, it turns out, that it doesn't have the greater-than,less-than and pipe key .

[image]

See image,see the key between left shift and y key - that key is missing.

I know I can buy another keyboard, but in the spirit of unix, i would like to remap the capslock key to the missing key.

I looked at the file : /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de

But, got pretty confused.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running X and not Wayland, using `xmodmap` instead of `xkbd` will be a lot easier (though people will tell you that `xmodmap` is deprecated, but people have been telling this for a decade, and it's still there).

Very briefly: Run `xmodmap -pke`, find keycode for capslock and greater/less key, run `xmodmap -e 'keycode 123 = ...`, where `123` is the keycode for capslock, and `...` is the definition for the greater/less key.

If it works, put the line into `~/.Xmodmap`, `~/.Xkeyboard` or whatever your display manager reads upon login.

Comment: @Sean You also need `clear Lock` in the `.Xmodmap` file, otherwise the key will still sometimes be interpreted as CapsLock and keyboard shortcuts involving pressing that key would fail sometimes.